# Как называется процесс приведения данных к более удобному с точки зрения программной обработки виду?

Tags: терминология

Типичная ситуация: какие-либо данные приложения хранятся во внешнем файле либо в базе данных. В идеале, чтобы эти данные должны быть структурированы так, чтобы их было удобно программно обрабатывать, но в реальности это, как правило, не так: "сырые" данные приходится перерабатывать, то есть приводить к такому виду, чтобы доступ к ним был легче (часто используются ассоциативные массивы).

Как называется процесс этот приведения "сырых" данных к более удобному виду?

Вероятно, "маппинг" - неправильный ответ. Насколько я знаю, маппинг - это (на уровне концепции) установление соответствия между двумя наборами данных. У нас же набор данных один и тот же, разница лишь в формате.

Comment: структуризация?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, тогда уж "реструктуризация" :)

Comment: Реструктуризация - это когда существующие структуры переделывают на новый лад, а первый раз - просто структуризация. (у нас обычно так)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В одном из пройденных мной уроков по реакт (в данном случае неважно) преподаватель преобразовывал в момент получения приходящие к нему с сервера данные для последующего более удобного обращения к ним.

Он массив объектов вида `[{article_id: value, article_text: value}]` преобразовывал в объект вида `{article_id: article_text}` и для получения конкретного текста ему не нужно теперь было каждый раз перебирать массив.

Собственно, вполне подходит под определение "У нас же набор данных один и тот же, разница лишь в формате".

Он называл это словом "нормализация данных".
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нормальная_форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Не знаю, есть ли вот прям такой термин в книжках, но думаю это выражение вполне уместно применить вместо фразы "приведение ко второй нормальной форме", которая точно валидна - на работе у нас ее постоянно используют.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! В принципе то, что я прочитал в приведённой Вами ссылке, имеет отношение к теме данного вопроса. Если никто более точного термина не приведёт (что, похоже, так и будет), то Вы выиграете этот конкурс.

Answer (score 0):

я бы назвал форматирование - приведение данных к определённому формату.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ru/SSEP7J_10.1.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.1.1.doc/t_cr_rptstd_wrkdat_format_data.html
пример
изначально есть несколько дат записанных в разном формате
**12.10.2011** после форматирования **12.10.2011** а если форматировать в Unix Time Stamp **1317427200**
**12.10.01** после форматирования **12.10.2001** а если форматировать в Unix Time Stamp **11001894400**
**12 октября 1991** после форматирования **12.10.1991** а если форматировать в Unix Time Stamp **686275200**
можно назвать и типизацией но на мой взгляд назвать этот процесс форматированием было бы правильнее)
типизацией я бы назвал опираясь больше на морфологию языка, если есть типы данных то процесс приведения приведения данных к этим типам должен называться типизация.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85